# setup.py's sdist, bdist and install behaving differently regarding data_files

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, data-files

I'm trying to distribute web assets along with a web app that I'm trying to package, but I'm failing miserably. I don't understand why I have a different list of files installed or packages when I run bdist, sdist, or install.

### Project Layout

The project runs with python 3 on Arch. The results are the same with Py3 on Raspbian.
 I've done a very trimmed down version to make things simpler, which I describe here.

The files layout is as follow :

```
data/index.html  
MANIFEST.in
mylib.py
setup.py
```

The `MANIFEST.in` file is :

```
recursive-include data *
```

The `setup.py` is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='mylib',
      version='0.1.2',
      url='http://www.example.org',
      author='Foo',
      packages=find_packages(),
      data_files = [ ('share/mylib', ['data/index.html']) ]
)
```

*My goal is to install `index.html` in `PREFIX/share/mylib/index.html`.*

### Running setup.py

Now, `bdist` includes the file at the seemingly right location, while `sdist` and `install` just ignore it :

- **bdist**

Using bdist, I have the following files in the resulting tar :

```
./usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mylib-0.1.2-py3.3.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
./usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mylib-0.1.2-py3.3.egg-info/top_level.txt
./usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mylib-0.1.2-py3.3.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
./usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mylib-0.1.2-py3.3.egg-info/PKG-INFO
./usr/share/mylib/index.html
```

This is exactly what I want to be installed, perfect. However, I really want `sdist` and `install` to work, since I want to distribute this thing on PyPI and be able to install from source checkouts.

- **sdist**

When I untar the sdist file, everything seems ok and data is included :

```
...
mylib-0.1.2/data/
mylib-0.1.2/data/index.html
...
```

However, if I `sudo python setup.py install --record=log.txt` in the directory where it is untarred, the only file listed in the log is `/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mylib-0.1.2-py3.3.egg`. No trace of `data/index.html` anywhere ('/usr/local/share', '/usr/share')

- **install**

Same issue as sdist (I suppose this is expected). No trace of `data/index.html` anywhere ('/usr/local/share', '/usr/share').

I also tried to add a setup.cfg like this :

```
[install]
install-data=/usr/local/share/mylib/
install_data=/usr/local/share/mylib/
```

(I've added both install-data and install_data since docs state to use the later, while I saw other projects using the former). No luck.

### Epilogue

Now, I quite new to python and it's environment, I'm probably missing something obvious or misunderstanding how setuptools works. I've been reading the doc back an forth, reading stackoverflow's Q&A in data_files at great length, but didn't make any progress.

If someone could point me to the right direction to solve this, this would be great. A link to a simple project distributing assets would be a good read too. I just couldn't find one that gave me that "Ah ah!" moment.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Using `zip_safe=False` prevents the egg file from being zipped and might reveal your files in the filesystem when using the form `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this helps, as I always include my data files relative to the python packages they go with. Additionally to the `MANIFFEST.in`, you'd have a `package_data` key in `setup.py`:

```
setup(name='mylib',
  version='0.1.2',
  url='http://www.example.org',
  author='Foo',
  packages=find_packages(),
  package_data={'package_name': 'package_dir/data/*'}

)
```

this would put the data to `site-packages/mylib-0.1.2/data`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @knitti, but I'd really like to have them in data_files instead, and put them in a sensible place on the filesystem.