# Include file in bdist_wheel but not sdist

Tags: python, setuptools

Many people have complained about `setuptools` not including things mentioned in `package_data` when making an `sdist`. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14159430/1485877) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612733/including-non-python-files-with-setup-py#comment11651991_1857436) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21305338/1485877).) However, it appears that this was changed at some point, so that items mentioned in `package_data` are included not only in `bdist_wheel`s but in `sdist`s also. My problem is that I want the old behavior; I want a file (namely, a compiled executable) to be included in the `bdist_wheel`, but not the `sdist`. How do I do that now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Disclaimer

Although it's technically possible, beware that when the source dist doesn't contain the file and wheel does, you will end up in having different installations of the same package for the same metadata, which is a bad behaviour. In the example below,

```
$ pip install spam --only-binary=spam  # force installation from wheel
```

will install `file.txt`:

```
$ pip show -f spam | grep file.txt
  spam/file.txt
```

while

```
$ pip install spam --no-binary=spam  # force installation from source dist
```

will not. This is a definite source for introducing new errors and no user will ever say thanks to you for this decision.

---

If you are really sure this is what you need: you can exclude the file in `MANIFEST.in`. Example:

```
project
├── spam
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── file.txt
├── MANIFEST.in
└── setup.py
```

#### `MANIFEST.in`

```
exclude spam/file.txt
```

#### `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='spam',
    version='0.1',
    packages=['spam'],
    package_data={'spam': ['file.txt']},
)
```

Building wheel:

```
$ python setup.py bdist_wheel >/dev/null 2>&1 && unzip -l dist/spam-*.whl | grep file.txt
    0  04-17-2019 21:25   spam/file.txt
```

Building source dist:

```
$ python setup.py sdist --formats=zip >/dev/null 2>&1 && unzip -l dist/spam-*.zip | grep file.txt
<empty>
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is so horrible? Is the idea that when you distribute an sdist, you as the maintainer should make sure there are no binaries in the package directory? Is there a way to build binaries so that they only appear in build/ and not the original package directory?